# Relative Path to OpenType Font in LyX

Tags: lyx, opentype

I am trying to use custom OpenType fonts (using `LuaLaTeX` and the `fontspec` package) in a LyX document under version control. The document is potentially accessed by others on different machines, so I decided to ship the .otf files in a subdirectory of the document's folder rather than relying on them being installed on the system. In other words, I just wanted to have the document in a compilable state as soon as it is checked out from version control *without the need of installing the otf files*.

This is how I wanted to add the fonts in the document's LaTeX Preamble:

```
\setmainfont{foo}[
    Path = mypath,
    UprightFont = foo-regular.otf,
    BoldFont = foo-bold.otf,
    ItalicFont = foo-it.otf,
    BoldItalicFont = foo-boldit.otf,
]
```

As long as `mypath` is an *absolute* path, everything works fine. As soon as I want to use a *relative* path here (because absolute paths don't make sense for files under version control) the fonts are not found any more.

Is there any solution to either (a) make a relative path work here or (b) somehow determine the absolute path of the current folder (*not* LyX's temporary folder where the document is actually compiled) and plug it in at `mypath`? Or is there any other obvious solution that I have overlooked?

Comment: did you try `./mypath` ?

Comment: I did. Doesn't work. I think the problem is that LyX copies its files to a temporary directory for compiling them. But it doesn't know that it has to copy the font files there. So both `path` and `./mypath` refer to said temporary directory, which does not contain the otf files (as LyX did not copy them there).

Comment: This theme pops up quite regularly. Imho only the lyx developers can do something about it. It should be possible to add "required resources" to a lyx document which is copied along with other resources (it should be possible, after all graphics and bib seems to work).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I could not find an option to add required files in a generic way. There is graphics and bibliographies, yes sure, and relative paths work perfectly there. And then there is "Insert -> File -> ...", but this also handles specific types of content only (text files, TeX files, child LyX files) if I understand it correctly. I could not find a generic way of saying "please also include file XY when copying files to your temporary folder".

Comment: Well you could try the equivalent of `%\input{font.otf}`. Or \iffalse \input{font.otf} \fi. Lyx will probably not realize that the file isn't \input at all.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your suggestion! Can you elaborate a bit on it? Where would I put the `\input`, how would I use it, and why would a relative path work there?

Comment: I'm not a lyx user. I have no idea how insert->file exactly works and if you can misuse it for this. But it seems logical that lyx has to copy such files to the tmp-directory too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, if I choose the way with `\iffalse ... \fi` at the beginning of my document, inserting a font file via "Insert -> File -> Child Document" in place of the `...`, then the font file ends up in the temporary folder. However, some kind of name mangling happens along the way, so e.g. the font `fonts/Calluna/exljbris-Calluna-Regular.otf`ends up as `25_home_simon_Documents_git-repo_fonts_Calluna_exljbris-Calluna-Regular.tex`, where the `25` seems to be a counter. I have no idea how I could "unmangle" this name. At this point I think I will give up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: another shot in the dark, did you try placing the file in the same directory as the *.lyx ?

Comment: @EladDen Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately it does not work, either. The problem remains the same: LyX does not copy the otf files to its temporary directory, to which the relative path points during compile time. So again it does not find the font files.

Comment: Suggestions: 1) try adding prepending your paths with \input@path (in some appropriate way), which is defined by LyX to refer to the original directory; 2) open a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome and request the feature of taking arbitrary file dependencies into account

Comment: @G.M. You are my hero! \input@path does the trick, thanks a lot! Here is what works (supposing the otf files are in a subdirectory called "fonts" under the original directory):  Setting `Path = \input@path ,` and then setting `UprightFont = fonts/foo-regular.otf,` etc., surrounding everything with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I could solve it (thanks to the help of G.M.). Suppose the otf files are in a subdirectory called "fonts" that lies under the directory that contains the main LyX file:

```
\setmainfont{foo}[
    Path           = \input@path,
    UprightFont    = fonts/foo-regular.otf,
    BoldFont       = fonts/foo-bold.otf,
    ItalicFont     = fonts/foo-it.otf,
    BoldItalicFont = fonts/foo-boldit.otf,
]
```

As G.M. explained, `\input@path` refers to the original directory (i.e. *not* the temporary directory where everything will be compiled).

**Update:**
In my original solution, I had everything surrounded with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. However, as G.M. also mentioned, LyX's LaTeX Preamble already provides this. So this is not necessary here and might indeed even cause trouble.

Comment: Note that the LyX preamble is already between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. Calling `\makeatother` early may cause unrelated problems.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you for pointing this out. I will update my answer accordingly.